# Prevent Navigation after Form Submit using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I am trying to prevent the browser from going to the url of my form, i.e. the "action" attribute of the .
As I am using javascript to submit the form, I don't know how to prevent the browser from going to another url.

**Here is the code which I am using to build the form**

```
document.getElementById("nonStaticField").innerHTML = `
<p style="font-size: 0.8em;">Als letzten Schritt bitte die Rechnung auswählen und hochladen</p>
<form id="fullform" action="showRechnungsInput" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="einreichen">
<input type="hidden" name="rechnungsnummer" value="${sessionStorage.getItem("rechnungsnummer")}">
<input type="hidden" name="abrechnungszeitraum" value="${sessionStorage.getItem("abrechnungszeitraum")}"
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
<input id="dateiupload" type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
</form>`;
document.getElementById("actionButton").innerText="Hochladen";
document.getElementById("actionButton").setAttribute("onclick","submitForm()");
```

**Here is the code I am using to submit the form**

```
function submitForm()
{
    document.getElementById("fullform").submit();
}
```

All is working fine except I don't want the browser to redirect me to "showRechnungsInput(.php)"

Comment: Your JavaScript is submitting the form which is the same as the normal form behaviour. What you want to do instead is serialize the form and post the data with AJAX instead of submitting it. You also want to prevent the normal submit behaviour by adding and on submit event to the form and event.preventdefault and return false. Hopefully there is enough here to help you find your way as I don't have time right now to add a complete answer.

Comment: I know it is possible to do this with javascript, but is it possible to do this without using javascript to send the request, i.e. using the default submit but still preventing the navigation on submit?

Comment: I cannot see how it would be possible, the form has to submit to the action if you don't want to use AJAX. Your best bet would be to have have the response at showRechnungsInput redirect the user back to the current page. i.e. showRechnungsInput handles the post data and then send back a 303 response code with a location header.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback Mark! After doing some more research I now am also assuming this is impossible to do, assuming you dont want to change the browser's source code, as the HTML submits behaviour requires to leave the page to make the request. I have now implemented fetch() to make my requests, and anybody else running into the same issue, I advise to do the same.